# How Autofac factories choose between passed parameter & resolved value

Tags: c#, autofac

I am working on a MVP implementation in WinForms app. My Presenter class takes both view and model as constructor parameters. It then sets the model property on view, calls for data binding and shows the view. My model requires some services to instantiates and has a factory method for the same. My presenter has a factory method to received this model and the view parameter is resolved through registration. Here is the code sample:

```
public class Presenter{
    public delegate Presenter Factory(ViewModel viewModel);
    public Presenter(ViewModel viewModel, IView<ViewModel> view){
        view.ViewModel = viewModel;
        view.BindModel();
        view.Show();
    }
}

public class ViewModel{
    public delegate ViewModel Factory(int modelId);

    //This collection is used by WinForms to show dropdown list 
    //and selected value is set as parent id on model
    public IEnumerable<Parent> ParentPropertyCollection {get; set;}

    //This constructor create a new model
    public ViewModel(IModelRepository repository, IParentRepository parentRepository){
        //Initiate the parent collection using parentRepository for selection through dropdown on form. repository is used for sending the updates back.
    }

    //This constructor fetches existing model
    public ViewModel(int modelId, IModelRepository repository,
        IParentModelRepository parentRepository){
        //fetch model data and set model properties using repository
        //Also populate parent collection.
    }
}

public class Navigator{
    public Navigator(IContainer container){
        _container = container;
    }

    public void ShowModelForm(int modelId){
        var modelFactory = container.Resolve<ViewModel.Factory>;
        var model = modelFactory(modelId);
        var presenterFactory = container.Resolve(Presenter.Factory);
        var presenter = presenterFactory(model);
    }

    public void NewModelForm(){
        var model = _container.Resolve<ViewModel>();
        var presenterFactory = container.Resolve<Presenter.Factory>();
        var presenter = presenterFactory(model);
}
```

There are few reasons for adapting this structure. I do not want multiple presenters for new and edit model scenarios. There are many entities and creating separate presenter for each operation is just way too much work. Secondly, I cannot have multiple parameters in the presenter as Autofac gave me error, that it could not choose the constructor for the factory. Third, I did not add repository parameters to presenter as it need not have dependency on them, just because model needs them.

**[EDIT: adding some more code for clarity. Also fixed issues with ViewModel class]**

```
public interface IView<T> where T:class{
    T ViewModel {get; set;}
    BindModel();
}
```

The way I do dependency resolution is pretty standard. I do not want the container to be injected everywhere. I do the registration in the startup code and pass the container to Navigator class for resolution. Navigator is typically at module level and handles the navigation within module.

Here is snippet of the resolution for the code above

```
builder.RegisterType<ViewModel>();
builder.RegisterType<ModelForm>().As<IView<ViewModel>>();
builder.RegisterType<Presenter>();
builder.RegisterType<Navigator>();
builder.Register(c=> _container).As<IContainer>();
```

**[Edit finished]**

Coming to the issue I am facing, when I pass the vm parameter to the presenter for an existing model, it creates and passes the model properly. However, inside the presenter, when resolving the IView, it instantiates the view model again for a new empty model instance and assigns the new instance to view rather than the passed on by presenter. I am not sure why this is happening.

Comment: Could you show the code of the IView<T> implementation?

Comment: IView<T> has really no dependency on T. It just declares the property ViewModel of type T. That's about it. This interface is to prevent the view model being set to any other type. In the implementation, if I try to resolve it to a new instance to ensure it is not null, does that impact in any way?

Comment: This isn't entirely clear. You mention a "vm" parameter but there isn't any - assuming you're talking about the `viewModel` parameter, it'd help if you didn't abbreviate. Further, "inside the presenter, when resolving the IView" - I don't see any resolution code in the `Presenter` class. It looks instead like `IView<T>` is provided by Autofac. If you're getting a second `ViewModel` that is already on `IView<T>` then chances are `IView<T>` either has a constructor parameter for it or is set up for property injection. It would help to see more.

Comment: And something to be aware of: If you pass a parameter to a resolve operation, it only goes _literally to the thing being resolved_ - it doesn't get passed all the way down the stack to every dependency being resolved in all chains. [There is documentation on this.](http://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq/injecting-global-parameters.html)